# How to let table layout fit 100% of the container with

Tags: c#, tablelayoutpanel

How can I give a tablelayoutpanel a width of 100% so it will fill the parent container and also resizes the table when resizing the window.

My form looks like this now:

[image]

I want to add rows dynamically so the result will be some like this:

[image]

It would be nice if the table would fit the splitcontainer panel. Someone knows how to do this?

This is my current code to add rows to the table:

```
tableLayoutPanel1.CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Outset;
tableLayoutPanel1.GrowStyle = TableLayoutPanelGrowStyle.AddRows;

tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "first row:", Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left, AutoSize = true });
tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "second row:", Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left, AutoSize = true });
tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "third row:", Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left, AutoSize = true });
tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "4th row:", Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left, AutoSize = true });
tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "5th row:", Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left, AutoSize = true });
tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "6th row:", Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left, AutoSize = true });
tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "7th row:", Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left, AutoSize = true });
```

I can set the column and rows to a width or height of 100% so how can I just set the table with to 100%?

```
// 
// tableLayoutPanel1
// 
this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 1;
this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 100F));
this.tableLayoutPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
this.tableLayoutPanel1.Name = "tableLayoutPanel1";
this.tableLayoutPanel1.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.No;
this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 2;
this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle());
this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle());
this.tableLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(754, 169);
//this.tableLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100F, 169);//pseudo code
this.tableLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 0;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to set the DockStyle to Fill

You can do this in the designer using the `Dock` property and selecting Fill from the dropdown, or by code:

```
this.tableLayoutPanel1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
```

Comment: Ah that was easier that I thought. Thank you!